# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^n x^{1/n} } dx$ using Beppo Levi theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I'm trying to find  $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^n x^{1/n} } dx$. My numerical test with large numbers instead of the infinity shows that result is 1 (I suppose). Also I tried to apply some facts from real analysis. For example,  [Beppo Levi theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwYMl.png).

So, can I just swap the integral and limit by this theorem?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need such an exchange. With $x=n\tan^{2}t$,$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-1/n}dx}{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}}&=\int_0^{\pi/2}2n^{1-1/n}\sin^{1-2/n}t\cos^{2n+2/n-3}tdt\\&=n^{1-1/n}\text{B}\left(1-\frac{1}{n},\,n+\frac{1}{n}-1\right)\\&=n^{1-1/n}\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{n}-1\right)}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}\\&\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\sim}1.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: (DCT)

For all $n \geqslant 2$, we have $\displaystyle\left(1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^{-n}x^{-1/n} \leqslant \begin{cases}\left(1 + \frac{x}{2} \right)^{-2}, &x \geqslant 1\\x^{-1/2}, &0 < x < 1 \end{cases}$

Comment: What does abbreviation "DCT" mean?

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem.  If $|f_n(x)| \leqslant g(x)$ and $\int_0^\infty g$ exists, then  $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^\infty f_n = \int_0^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n $

Comment: @margo Not to be focused with [another CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), which is more similar in spirit to the titular theorem.